# Signature tag isnt being populated in SOAP UI in the request

Tags: soapui

I am facing a wierd issue while generating soap UI , I am not able to sign my message even though I have added my jks to "Keystores" and added Signature in the Outgoing WS - security configuration .

When I apply this configuration to my request in SOAP UI , it doesnt add the signature part .
It simply add the following Security tag only.

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My JKS was the problem . It was incorrect and only contained public key , hence I regenerated it and followed the earlier mentioned process . I could generate the signature then .